# How to avoid SQLalchemy removing zero count from query results

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a multi-vendor sales site where I want to count the sales per seller each day.

So I first create a subquery to get the dates from the last 365 days:

```
date_series = func.generate_series(min_date , todays_date, timedelta(days=1))
trunc_date = func.date_trunc('day', date_series)
subquery = session.query(trunc_date.label('day')).subquery()
```

Then I put this into the main query to get the actual counts:

```
query = session.query(subquery.c.day, func.count(Sale.id), Vendor.name)
    
query = query.outerjoin(Sale, subquery.c.day == func.date_trunc('day', Sale.timestamp))
query = query.outerjoin(Product, Sale.product_id == Product.id)
query = query.outerjoin(Vendor, Product.vendor_id == Vendor.id)

query = query.group_by(subquery.c.day, Vendor)
query = query.order_by(subquery.c.day.desc())

counts = query.all()
```

Problem is, when I include the **Vendor** to the **group_by** it doesn't return the days that have 0 count sales, just as if it involuntary goes from an outerjoin query to an innerjoin one.

If I query just to see the count of **Sales** per day, removing the **Vendor** in the query and in the **group_by**, it return columns with 0 sales as well (but then I don't see the count per Vendor, I just get the count of all Sales each day).

How can I do this query without the 0 count Sales days being removed from the results by the **group_by**?

***EDITS:***

Generated query:

```
SELECT anon_1.day AS anon_1_day, vendor.name AS vendor_name, count(sales.id) AS count_1
FROM (SELECT date_trunc(%(date_trunc_1)s, generate_series(%(generate_series_1)s, %(generate_series_2)s, %(generate_series_3)s)) AS day) AS anon_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON anon_1.day = date_trunc(%(date_trunc_2)s, sales.timestamp) LEFT OUTER JOIN product ON sales.product_id = product.id LEFT OUTER JOIN vendor ON product.vendor_id = vendor.id GROUP BY anon_1.day, vendor.name ORDER BY anon_1.day DESC
```

Tables:

```
Sale >- Product >- Vendor
```

Current query results:

```
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 11, 0, 0), None, None)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 10, 0, 0), None, None)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 9, 0, 0), None, None)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 8, 0, 0), Vendor_1, 10)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 8, 0, 0), Vendor_2, 3)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 7, 0, 0), Vendor_1, 9)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 7, 0, 0), Vendor_2, 11)
```

Wanted query result:

```
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 11, 0, 0), Vendor_1, 0)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 11, 0, 0), Vendor_2, 0)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 10, 0, 0), Vendor_1, 0)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 10, 0, 0), Vendor_2, 0)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 9, 0, 0), Vendor_1, 0)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 9, 0, 0), Vendor_2, 0)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 8, 0, 0), Vendor_1, 10)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 8, 0, 0), Vendor_2, 3)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 7, 0, 0), Vendor_1, 9)
(datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 7, 0, 0), Vendor_2, 11)
```

Comment: If there are no sales for a day do you store a value 0 or just not store a row for that day? Your description sounds like you do not store a row. If that the case you need to create a **left outer join** then translate the NULL value returned to 0.

Comment: I only store sales that have happened, so this query counts the rows in the Sales table. I believe the sqlalchemy outerjoin. does in fact create a left outer join? Hence why I get zero count results when i dont include Vendor in the group_by. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry I did not mention. You need to outer join with with your date parameter.

Comment: @Belayer. Thanks, but I might be slow, cause I thought I did that already in this line: query.outerjoin(Sale, subquery.c.day == func.date_trunc('day', Sale.timestamp)). Any chance you could be a bit more specific?

Comment: Looks like I'm the sole one. Is there anyway you can update your question and post the generated query and the actual table ddls.

Comment: @Belayer, yessir. Added + tried to show query outputs. Not sure what ddls means though, but hoping this makes it possible for you to spot the problem.